# ClassNotFoundException thrown unless applet opened from Desktop

Tags: java, html, applet

I've been looking through the other questions regarding this issue but didn't find any that were similar to my situation. I have made an applet in Java and I noticed that I can only open the HTML(with ) involved from my desktop. If I attempt to open it from any other spot on the computer, it will throw the ClassNotFoundException despite the class being in the same folder as the html file.

What would be causing this?

Thank You.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> .. </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<BODY BGCOLOR="#F0F0F0">
<p><center><img src = "Reunion2013.gif"></center></p>
<p><font size="5"><b><center>Murdock High School Alumni - It's Time to Party Together,        
<center></b></font></p> 

<table border="0">
<tr>
<td><b>Instructions</b><p></p></td>

</tr>

<tr><td>
<OL><LI>Fill in all information below. For State, enter the two-letter abbreviation.   
<LI>To restart your registration at any time, click the <i>Clear</i> button.
<LI>To submit your registration, click the Register button (A summary will display <br>
</br>
</td></tr>
</OL>
</table>
<p><center><APPLET CODE="ReunionRegistration.java" WIDTH=650 HEIGHT=250></center></p>
</APPLET>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Don't you have there absolute path to the `.jar` file?

Comment: I'm pretty new to applets. Where would I find that?

Comment: edit your post and paste there your `html` code...especially the part, where you call the `applet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rewrite your code to access your applet via

```
<applet code="ReunionRegistration.class" WIDTH=650 HEIGHT=250 />
```

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I didn't compile before I tried to open it.

Comment: Eh? There can't be anything wrong yet... I expect, that problem exists between keyboard and chair ;) You really should check out, if you've got there valid and executable `.class` file in that folder with your `.html` file...

Answer (score 2):

The code attribute expects a **class**, not a Java file.

```
APPLET CODE="ReunionRegistration.java"
```

should be

```
APPLET CODE="ReunionRegistration.class"
```

Please see this reference: [Java Applet Syntax](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/special/applet.html).